# Second class of multiple classes can't override style

Tags: reactjs

button.module.css

```
.general_button {
    width: 100%; 
}
```

button.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './button.module.css';

const GeneralButton = ({ text, className}) => {
    return (
        <button className={`${styles.general_button} ${className}`}>
            <p className={styles.text}>{text}</p>
        </button>
    );
};

export { GeneralButton };
```

app.module.css

```
.next_btn {
    width: 35%;
}
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './app.module.css';
import { GeneralButton } from './components/Buttons';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <GeneralButton className={classes.next_btn} text='next' />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

When I used button component from app, button component is working with 'width:100%'. I would like to be button component is with 'width: 35%'.

[This is when I inspect browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsMWB.png)

[This is when I inspect browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIGcq.png)

Comment: Have you tried setting the button's `display` property to `block` or `inline-block`?

Comment: Yes, I already tried. But it can't.

Comment: `width: 35% !important`; ?

Comment: But I don't want to use ' !important '. Another way?

Comment: Then ```<button className={`${className} ${styles.general_button}`}>```?

Comment: No, it also can't.

Comment: Check first if your class is being applied to the html element in DOM

Comment: When I inspect from browser,
`
<button class="styles_general_button__2k82W styles_next_btn__3iSb4">
         <p class="PoppinsSemiBold styles_text__GgijV">Next</p>
</button>
`
`
.styles_general_button__2k82W {
    width: 100%;
}
`
`
.styles_next_btn__3iSb4 {
    width: 35%
}
`
width: 35% is with through line.

Comment: That means that a more specific rule is overriding it.

Comment: My error or react issue?

Answer (score -1):

Since both classes are equally specific, your app chooses whichever comes later in the stylesheet. Unfortunately you have much control over this order since it is likely generated by webpack (or whatever bundler you happen to be using).

One of the main benefits of using modular css is to avoid having to fight specificity battles such as this, so I would suggest reworking the button component slightly - something like this might work:

```
const GeneralButton = ({ text, variant }) => {
  let buttonClass = styles.general_button;

  if (variant === "next") {
    buttonClass = styles.next_button;
  }

  return (
    <button className={buttonClass}>
      <p className={styles.text}>{text}</p>
    </button>
  );
};
```

The advantage here is that the button lays out the options for how to present it and the parent component just selects the type it needs. This makes it safer to re-work the button component in the future since it encapsulates all of it's states.